# Getting Optional for String display

Tags: ios, swift, string

For an Apple Watch extension I am presenting an AlertController and I am getting a display like "Preset Optional(2)" instead of "Preset 2" - below is my code. How do I get rid of the Optional (didn't think Strings had them)

```
if let s = info["description"]
{
    let action = WKAlertAction(title: "OK", style: WKAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { () -> Void in
         //
    })

    //let arr = s.componentsSeparatedByString("_")
    let arr = s.characters.split("_", maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false).map(String.init)
    self.presentAlertControllerWithTitle("Preset \(arr[0])", message: "\n\(arr[1])", preferredStyle: WKAlertControllerStyle.Alert, actions: [action])
}
```

Here is how info["description"] is derived:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject])
{
    if let info = message as? Dictionary<String,String>{            
        if let s = info["description"]
        {
            ...
```

Comment: Just for future reference, any variable can be an optional.

Comment: Try to force unwrap like Preset \(arr[0]) !

Comment: @VishalSonawane **NO.**  You should never force unwrap anything unless you have a really good reason to.

Comment: @VishalSonawane NEVER force unwrap. If its nil that will cause a crash

Comment: @JAL and @ Simon yeah I didn't thought about it. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Here is the content of `s`: "Optional(2)_1.fm Otto's Baroque Music" - right after `if let s = info["description"]`

Comment: So how do I get rid of that optional?

Comment: You get rid of it by not putting it here in the first place. The issue is actually earlier in your code, in `message`, since we see that `s` is a String which *already* contains "Optional(2)" **as a String**, not as an Optional anymore. You must have forgot to unwrap `Int(yourIntAsText)` somewhere earlier or something similar.

Comment: Yup. `let thisDictionary:[String:String] = ["description":"\(index)_\(p1)\n\n\(p2)"]` fixed: `let thisDictionary:[String:String] = ["description":"\(index!)_\(p1)\n\n\(p2)"]` - that fixed it. Thanks for all your help!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unwrap the contents of the array or use the nil coalescing operator:

```
if let str = arr[0] as? String {
    let title = "Preset \(str)"
}
```

or

```
"Preset \(arr[0]) ?? \(someDefaultValue)"
```

If `s` is a `String?` you want to unwrap that first:

```
if let s = info["description"] as? String {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: if let str = arr[0] as? String

Conditional cast from 'String' to 'String' always succeeds warning.

Comment: @EricD Yep, assumed the array was of optional Strings.  We would need to see what the contents are.

Comment: @RadagasttheBrown that doesn't make sense.  You're casting a `[String : AnyObject]` dictionary as `[String : String]` and then taking an array for the key `"description"`.

Comment: @JAL No he's getting a string from the dictionary, and then using `split` on the characters, to get an array. Although I'm certainly confused where the optional comes from.... must be part of the original string.

Comment: AnyObject because that conforms to the WatchConnectivity didReceiveMessage method. I am sending Dictionary of <String,String>. The key for description is a String like "1_Here is the info" - and I need to get the 1 out of the string and use that separately.

Comment: @EricD Ah I see, the value returned from the dictionary is an optional string.  Edited my answer to reflect what I think you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks. When I do the unwrap if `s`, I get an error: `Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?" - but of course I can't use '!' either.